# Можно ли разрабатывать логику приложения для android на php?

Tags: php, android

Можно ли разрабатывать логику приложения для android на php? На сколько это нормально и с какими ограничениями и сложностями можно столкнуться, которые могут возникнуть из-за особенностей языка php?

Comment: вряд ли, под Android пишут на Java, Kotlin, C++, C# и языках, которые запускаются под JVM или Dalvik, вроде ещё на JS можно, но на мой взгляд это извращение

Comment: Можно попробовать использовать Zend Studio или JPHP. Но, скорее всего, проблем и ограничений встретится немало.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете строить вашу бизнес-логику на сервере на любом языке, но само приложение обязательно пишется на одном из языков, указанном в первом комментарии к вопросу.

Comment: Это неправда. С использованием той же Cordova весь код приложения выходит на JavaScript. Да и с использованием всяких JPHP, думаю, получится описать логику приложения (а ведь это главное) на PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите вынести логику на бэкенд, хоть PHP, хоть Node.js

Главный подводный камень здесь, что PHP это динамический язык, а основные языки для разработки на Андроид -- статические.

Как пример, логическое значение, в Java это может быть только true или false. В PHP динамическая переменная по умолчанию null, если вы забудете ее проинициализировать и отправите Андроид клиенту null вместо true или false, он очень удивится :)